# Is it possible to only view/plot non-Interaction events on google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a large numbers of events within one category, and some of the non-interaction events fire an order of magnitude more that the other events.

That is why when plotting some of the least performing event actions, the graph displays a straight line for those events?

[image]

I was wondering if it would be possible to select/deselect non-Interaction events from the graph or only display the selected event actions without total events?

Or should I divide the events into multiple categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot distinguish a non-interaction event in the interface if you do not make it identifiable by the name.

Divide the events into multiple categories or using a naming convention to distinguish events or assign a label or a custom dimension, they are ways to represent those events in reports.